# Ruby: find items in hash by values

Tags: ruby

I'm currently working with a ruby hash that looks like the following:

```
{"employee"=>[{"name"=>"john", "level"=>"1", "position"=>"S1"}, 
              {"name"=>"bill", "level"=>"2", "position"=>"S2"}]}
```

These are two examples of employees and I need to be able to pull employees out by values. For example I'd like to get all employees who's level == 2, or all employees who's position == S1.

How would I do this in Ruby?

Comment: I recommend using symbols as keys.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i pulled the code from a dump, they are internally keys, does that change how you would solve it, or are you simply making syntax suggestions.

Comment: @Jeremy It's just a suggestion.

Comment: Keep in mind that this is ridiculously inefficient and loses pretty much all the efficiency of a hashtable.

Comment: Which part is inefficient? selecting an item from the table, or strings as keys?

Comment: If it's a single element from a hash of arrays of hashes it's very normal. If it's the entire structure then it's overly complex, but I suspect it's the first case.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`Hash#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M002872) or [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002191).

```
level_2_employees = infoHash["employee"].select {|k| k["level"] == "2"}
```

This will return an array of employee info hashes according to your criteria. Be sure to put quotes around value for level

Answer (score 5):

```
ehash = {"employee"=>[{"name"=>"john", "level"=>"1", "position"=>"S1"}, 
                      {"name"=>"bill", "level"=>"2", "position"=>"S2"}]}
ehash['employee'].find_all { |e| e['level'] == 2}
ehash['employee'].find_all { |e| e['position'] == 'S2'}
```